# What does the FORMULA.FILL function do in Excel 4 Macros?

Tags: excel, macros, excel-4.0, xlm

I'm translating some functions written in Excel 4 XLM macros into VBA. One of the functions called within the macro I'm currently translating is `FORMULA.FILL`. I cannot seem to find any documentation of what this function does. Could anyone provide detail about this function, its parameters, what it does, its output, etc.?

**Update:**

Some more context...

```
=ALERT("Are you sure you want to Extract and Export Baseline Data?",1)
=IF(NOT(F3),RETURN())
=GET.DOCUMENT(88)
=ECHO(FALSE)
=WORKBOOK.ACTIVATE("Baseline export")
=unprotectsheet()
=RemoveFormulas()
=WORKBOOK.ACTIVATE("Baseline export")
=WORKBOOK.UNHIDE("Baseline Export")
=FORMULA.FILL("",'baseline export'!A2:C1000)
=DEFINE.NAME("Database",BaselineDatabase)
=DEFINE.NAME("Criteria",BaselineCriteria)
=DEFINE.NAME("Extract",BaselineExtract)
=EXTRACT()
=COUNTA('baseline export'!D:D)-1
=CALCULATION(3)
=ERROR(FALSE)
=FORMULA.REPLACE(not_applicable,not_applicable_value)
=ERROR(TRUE)
=FORMULA.FILL("Snapshot",OFFSET('baseline export'!A1,1,0,F17,1))
=FORMULA.FILL(Domain,OFFSET('baseline export'!B1,1,0,F17,1))
=FORMULA.FILL(Project,OFFSET('baseline export'!C1,1,0,F17,1))
=MATCH(Current_Reporting_Date,'baseline export'!D:D,0)
=IF(NOT(ISNA(F25)),FORMULA("Month",OFFSET('baseline export'!A1,Macro1!F25-1,0,1,1)))
=RestoreFormulas()
=WORKBOOK.ACTIVATE("baseline export")

=savebaselineexportworksheet(BaselineExportFilename)
=WORKBOOK.ACTIVATE(F5)
=FORMULA.FILL("",'baseline export'!A2:KX1000)
=WORKBOOK.HIDE("baseline export")
=WORKBOOK.ACTIVATE("export baseline")
=ECHO(TRUE)
=CALCULATION(1)

=ALERT("Baseline exported to Excel file: "&BaselineExportFilename,3)
=ALERT("… be sure to update your baseline-export-list .txt file and use your DataDrill Collector to upload the baseline export Excel file to the Database.",3)

=RETURN()
```

Comment: Gosh, it's been ages since I have worked with XLM. Can you show an example of `Formula.Fill`? My guess is `FORMULA.FILL` simply copies the formula down and has the same functionality as the `Autofill`.

Comment: @SiddharthRout added some more context for you

Comment: Thanks for the flashback.  It's probably been 20 years since I worked with that macro structure.  :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`=FORMULA.FILL("",'baseline export'!A2:C1000)`

The function above places "" (nothing) in cells `A2:C1000` on sheet `baseline export`.

Basically, it is clearing out those cells.

`FORMULA.FILL` was the function that was used when you wanted to put data or formulas into cells.

Comment: Thanks, this does appear to be what it does. I was just making sure I didn't miss any nuances.